# See minutes view in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

The day grid view shows the day by hours (1-23). How can I show it by minutes (ex: 1:00, 1:10, 1:20, etc...) instead of showing by hours (1, 2, 3, etc...).
[image]

Thanks in Advance. The full calendar version is FullCalendar v3.6.2.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration . Try to read the documentation more thoroughly!

Answer (score 1):

```
slotDuration: '00:05:00', //time slot. Jumps between 5 and 5 minutes
slotLabelInterval: 5,
slotLabelFormat: 'H(:mm)',
```